# Why do I not observe single/double escape peaks for K-40

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, gamma-rays

A question on gamma spectrometry here. If I'm looking at a background gamma spectrum with a big peak at 1460KeV (approximately 180 counts) and I attribute this peak to the presence of K-40, should I expect to see the single and double escape peaks for K-40? If I should expect to see them and I don't, can I then in fact rule out the possibility of this peak being due to K-40?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very hard to tell without knowing how the spectrum was produced (type and size of the detector, resolution, anticompton, ...). Anyway 180 counts do not seem so many. The single escape peak is normally weaker and the double escape even more, especially if you are just above the pair production threshold. Sounds reasonable that you may not have significant counts in those bins.

Comment: Also, if there's a 1460 keV gamma ray, there should be single and double escape peaks, regardless of the origin of the gamma. It may just be that they are too weak to see, since the pair production cross section is probably relatively small.